# How to use different type of parameter without creating new view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to create a list with a string and an int value at the same time like follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "IndexEvent", new { location = "location" })
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "IndexEvent", new { locationID = 1 })
```

It didn't work. I guess MVC controller didn't get the type difference of parameter. So, I had to make a new Action as "IndexEvenyByID" but it requires to have a new view. Since I wanted to keep it simple, is there any way to use same view with respect to different parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding two optional parameters to the `IndexEvent` action like this:

```
public ActionResult IndexEvent(string location = "", int? locationID = null)
```

Comment: I would personally prefer testing for a null int then a 0 based int (Who knows, maybe you'll want to use 0 as an index). That said, I would just put (string location, int? locationID)

Comment: Yes, sounds like a more general solution

Comment: Having to test for null parameters to determine how to retrieve data compared to having two actions that are dedicated in how the retrieve data can get messy fast and brings in questions such as what happens if someone mucks with the URL and neither is null or both?  Having separate actions is typically the cleanist approach

Comment: @Tommy - I agree, but this allows to avoid code duplication if action method is more complex then just getting the value.

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin - True, code duplication is bad, but most of the work from the action method should come from a different layer (service, etc) in which that duplication could be taken care of by using a shared function or some other method :)

Answer (score 1):

This should not require a new view or view model.  You should have two actions as you have described, but the code could be as follows:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetEvents(string location){
    var model = service.GetEventsByLocation(location);
    return View("Events", model);
}

public ActionResult GetEventsById(int id){
    var model = service.GetEventsById(id);
    return View("Events", model);
}
```

**Service**

```
public MyViewModel GetEventsByLocation(string location){
    //do stuff to populate a view model of type MyViewModel using a string
}

public MyViewModel GetEventsById(int id){
   //do stuff to populate a view model of type MyViewModel using an id
}
```

Basically, if your View is going to use the same view model and the only thing that is changing is how you get that data, you can completely reuse the View.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick to a single action and multiple type, you could use a object parameter.

```
public ActionResult GetEvents(object location)
{
    int locationID;
    if(int.TryParse(location, out locationID))
        var model = service.GetEventsByID(locationID);
    else
        var model = service.GetEventsByLocation(location as string);
    return View("Events", model);
}
```

Something like that (Not completly right but it gives you an idea). This, however, wouldn't really be a "clean" way to do it IMO.

(Edit)

But the 2 actions method is still by far preferable (eg. What happens if we're able to parse a location name into a int?)